# match_parent dont match parent's in small (ldpi/mdpi) android phones

Tags: android

I have 7 toogle buttons, representing each day a week :

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/parentToggle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglSun"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="SUN"
                android:textOn="SUN" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglMon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="MON"
                android:textOn="MON" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglTue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="TUE"
                android:textOn="TUE" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglWed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="WED"
                android:textOn="WED" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglThu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="THU"
                android:textOn="THU" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglFri"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="FRI"
                android:textOn="FRI" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tglSat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textOff="SAT"
                android:textOn="SAT" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Above's code work fine in big devices (hdpi).

However, when i try to run it to the smaller device (ldpi/mdpi), only SUN until WED displayed (3 toogles missing).

I think `match_parent` will count the device's `width` so all the views will be visible, but its not.

**Question** :

How to force the 7 toggle buttons in single row on smaller device **OR**  how to make the toggle buttons automatically create the 2nd rows if the device is to small?

Example :
1st row from SUN to WED
2nd row from THU to SAT

Thanks for your help.

**Note** : I want to avoid using `HorizontalListView` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following changes to your layout:

1. change layout_width to 0dp
2. add layout_weight="1"

The above is for each ToggleButton.

Comment: Thanks. Your code work, but the result is pretty ugly (im not blaming you) : http://i59.tinypic.com/qrn11k.png

Do you have any idea how to make it better?

Comment: Hm. I actually saw how it looks on hdpi device (not all buttons originally fit also) but with proportional sizing buttons looked, well, normal. I would change text size in the first place (for lpdi screen only).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) in your `xml`. Your activity's height overflow in small desvices.

**XML**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentToggle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglSun"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="SUN"
            android:textOn="SUN" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglMon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="MON"
            android:textOn="MON" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglTue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="TUE"
            android:textOn="TUE" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglWed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="WED"
            android:textOn="WED" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglThu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="THU"
            android:textOn="THU" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglFri"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="FRI"
            android:textOn="FRI" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglSat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="SAT"
            android:textOn="SAT" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I need horizontal linear layout

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to change your `LinearLayout` for a `RelativeLayout`. Their properties are almost similar, and the way to deal with them is the same.

For this, you have to add an extra property to every button: `android:layout_toRightOf`, and put the reference to the button placed on the left.

For the first button, you can use `android:align_ParentLeft="true"`

I hope this would help you :)

Comment: Will the 7 buttons become a single row if i use your method? I will try it soon, thanks

Comment: Thanks. Sorry i prefer to use linear layout. Its too bad i can only upvote once.